# After Data Science SE: Artificial Intelligence SE

Tags: discussion, on-topic, ai-stackexchange

The [Artificial Intelligence SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions) is now in private beta phase, and it looks like most questions asked there are on-topic here. There is already another SE with a large overlap, namely Data Science SE. What do you think of this new SE, and should we avoid another almost identical SE?

Comment: Smarter users would be a great start.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial, ouch. FWIW, I can't see who the users are.

Comment: @gung To clarify -- I still don't understand how the Data Science SE got green-lighted when it has about 80% overlap with Stats.SE, and the remaining 20% being composed of stats-specific computing questions. To my mind, AI is either an intractable computational goal (make a computer that can learn arbitrarily complex tasks without human intervention) or is entirely a subset of contemporary machine learning. But either greenlighting decision totally makes sense if one does not really understand what stats.SE does.

Comment: It's not up to us to "avoid" it or not. My guess is that what isn't on topic already here, &/or at [datascience.SE], is likely to be on topic on [cstheory.SE] (eg, they have a tag for [ai.artificial-intel](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai.artificial-intel) w/ 53 questions). I'm not sure if SE (or the larger information-seeking world) is ultimately benefited by increasingly narrow SE sites. I would think many of these would be better combined into a smaller number of stronger sites until there was really critical mass for a split.

Comment: Honestly, I think that the strength of SE is that it groups together these things -- so I can contribute to questions about things that I know about and learn about things that I don't know about. Splintering SE sites into narrowly-focused topics makes that more challenging to do: following the goings-on in 3 or 4 places, rather than 1 or 2. I don't see any upside to splintering SE topics.

Comment: @gung Perhaps "avoid" isn't the right word, but if a new SE is created and has a 80% overlaps with stats, it might mean some users aren't aware of what is on-topic on stats.  On http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/q/4/4 I listed different SE that has an AI tag.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, that seems like a good thing to do. Note, however, that I cannot see the thread b/c I am not a member there.

Comment: @gung I think you can join through http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, meh. On a different topic, you are probably aware that we have a [tag:artificial-intelligence] tag. However, it had no excerpt / wiki. I have added [one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/artificial-intelligence/info), in case you want to check / tweak it.

Comment: @gung Thanks. In the feedback from the AI site, it looks like the name "CV" isn't explicit enough to designate statistics / machine learning / optimization / AI. I agree.

Comment: I think all the problems around these new websites would can be solved by changing the site name to something like "data science and statistics". CV is clearly too obscure to signal what's on topic.

Comment: I don't see Stats name anything to do with AI. And Cross Validation is a very bad name.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial "CrossValidated" (which I think is a *great* name) is just a name. As a comparison, the SE site on cooking is called "Seasoned Advice". Its url address is `cooking.SE` and ours is `stats.SE`. I recall that SE does not allow site names to differ from their topics anymore, btw. Are you suggesting that we should rather get rid of our "custom name" too?

Comment: @amoeba I realize that the correspondence between the name and what is on-topic is, essentially, arbitrary. CV.SE could be called "bacon" and we'd still be able to moderate the forums to the same standards. The name is cute and clever for people who understand the field. But the proliferation of increasingly narrow SE sites which are, otherwise, on-topic elsewhere is precisely counterproductive. User kenorb doesn't see any relation between AI and statistics, which is clearly preposterous! Either AI is a farce or statistical concepts are paramount -- I know what side I'm on.

Comment: @GeneralAbrial: one thing to keep in mind about changing the name to "data science and statistics" is that we turn down questions that are of the data science realm but not of statistical nature (coding, database management, etc).

Comment: @CliffAB I actually think that statistical coding questions should be on topic but I'm pretty much alone there. Database questions have their own forum.

Comment: You should give it some time to brew. Currently the questions seem to be predominantly of a "too broad" kind by CV standards. If they keep doing this, then the site will die on its own. There's got to be sufficient sustainable number of new specific questions arriving for it survive.

Comment: @Aksakal amongst the non too broad questions, a good amount would be on-topic here.

Comment: The problem with the massive overlap between CV & the Data Science forum is that "data science" is to some extent just a buzz word of recent origin, not with CV's catchy name. It's a broad, fuzzy term whose meaning drifts from person to person. The same is true to a lesser extent of the definition of A.I. I'd rather see the D.S. forum closed to avoid such confusion, unless it survives as a mere adjunct of CV strictly for statistics-related coding questions. Until a clear definition of A.I. becomes widespread, I see no point in adding even more confusion with another overlapping site.

Comment: @SQLServerSteve, I agree on DS, it's a marketing fad, but A.I. is different. It tries to build a thinking machine. It happens so that lately statistical methods are popular in the field, but that's just a phase in the development of a field.

Comment: @Aksakal I agree to an extent. A.I. is definitely more well-defined than DS. It still gets used as a buzz word and catch-all term and its meaning also drifts, although not to the same degree. It is still difficult though to pin down exactly where statistics/machine learning etc. transition into A.I. Furthermore, "intelligence" is itself is not a simple thing to define, even biologically. Does is mean the use of abstract reason? Or any nervous system activity at all? If we could find a way to set crisp boundaries on these things I'd have fewer misgivings (I already have far fewer than with DS)

Comment: So if you would like to avoid having another Stack Exchange website with a large overlap with CV, you may want to cast some votes: [Technical questions are not getting closed](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/q/1279/4)

Answer (score 9):

I think that this kind of issue is endemic to SO and will only increase as sites proliferate.

A proposal: there should be a proposal process where users can vote to merge sites, resulting in a permanent redirect.

Really, what's in a name? Cross Validation is an excellent name to catch the attention of anyone who's actually exercised curiosity + healthy skepticism about "smart algorithms" and so on, but inasmuch as it serves as a clue, it's an easy one for people to miss.

Comment: There have been some SE merges in the past e.g. http://meta.video.stackexchange.com/q/353/2117 or http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/1904/452.