# Why do we have so many overlapping sites?

Tags: discussion

StackOverflow has multiple overlapping sites, i.e.

- Cross Validated
- Mathematics (has 19k statistics questions)
- MathOverflow (described as being a "Q&A for professional mathematicians", similar to Mathematics being a "Q&A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields")
- Data Science and BioInformatics

My question is, **what are the differences between these sites (specifically the 1st three)**?

Comment: This seems mostly like a question for meta.SE, rather than here. Basically, the SE system has a mechanism for proposing new sites (area 51) such that the sites will automatically launch if there is sufficient interest. People make different suggestions & some catch on. For related discussions of CV vs DS, see the threads categorized under the [datascience-stackexchange](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datascience-stackexchange) tag.

Comment: The answers can be found by visiting the sites and reading their help pages.  There is essentially *zero* overlap between CV and MO.  Although there is some with mathematics, it's far less than you would think: if you have an abstract theoretical question or a textbook exercise, Math is probably the place for it, but if you are concerned about applications or intuition, CV is the place to go.  (There's probably more overlap between Math and Physics etc. than there is with us.)  The DS site substantially overlaps CV--which perhaps is one reason it has had such little success.

Comment: Some reasons why sites overlap (not likely to include them all): (a) many questions may seem to touch on the scope of two or more sites (b) many won't study, or prefer to ignore, detailed advice about what's on-topic at any site and no mechanisms are perfect in flushing off-topic material (c) such advice may seem in turn unclear or ambiguous; even experienced people can disagree in good faith on where to draw lines.

Comment: also: [After Data Science SE: Artificial Intelligence SE](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4243/12359)